# Invalid OAuth signature on vimeo with Xamarin.Auth

Tags: c#, oauth, xamarin.ios, vimeo, xamarin.auth

I'm trying to call the vimeo REST API from within a Xamarin.iOS application, but I keep getting a 401: `The oauth_signature passed was not valid.`

Here's the code:

```cs
public async Task GetAll (string userId)
{
    var request = OAuth1.CreateRequest (
        "GET",
        new Uri ("http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2"),
        new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"user_id", userId},
            {"format", "json"},
            {"method", "vimeo.video.getAll"}
        },
        CONSUMERKEY, CONSUMERSECRET, TOKENSECRET);

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream ())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader (stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
        Console.WriteLine (request.RequestUri);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd ());
    }
}
```

The request looks week-formed, but it fails anyway. Any hint ?

Comment: I can't comment on what might be wrong with your code, but if you send your client id, and some example requests and responses to https://vimeo.com/help/contact I might be able to help you track down what the problem might be.

Comment: I tried and got a "we don't provide API support" type of answer. but Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparing the BaseString generated by `Xamarin.Auth` and the one generated by http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html I found out that the `oath_token` parameter was missing.

I fixed my issue by adding it manually:

```cs
public async Task GetAll (string userId)
{
    var request = OAuth1.CreateRequest (
        "GET",
        new Uri ("http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2"),
        new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"user_id", userId},
            {"format", "json"},
            {"method", "vimeo.video.getAll"},
            {"oauth_token", ACCESSTOKEN},
        },
        CONSUMERKEY, CONSUMERSECRET, TOKENSECRET);

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream ())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader (stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
        Console.WriteLine (request.RequestUri);
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd ());
    }
}
```